# Taylor Approximation of pi

Tags: taylor-expansion

Let `T` be an approximation of pi correct to `n` decimals. How can i prove that the approximation of `T + sinT` is accurate to 3n decimals?

Comment: Hint : $$\sin(x)=x-\frac{1}{3}x^3+O(x^5)$$

Comment: For T, I attempted to approximate pi using arctan(x) by Maclaurin Series, solve for x=1 and then multiply by four, but then I am having problems with that sinT series and the error of T+sinT. @peter